# "Make Single Instance Application" in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express, and I'd like my application to be single-instance. Various sources tell me that "Project Properties > Application > Make single instance application" would do such a thing. I can't, however, find this option in VC#2010 Express.

Is it absent from the Express version, or moved, or is it there and I really am just blind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing and sadly, there is no such thing in C#.

You might find what you are looking for here though: http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/SingleInstance.html